# ExpressionEngine Ignoring Simple Conditional and Parsing Plugin Code

Tags: expressionengine

I have an ExpressionEngine plugin wrapped in a simple `{if}` conditional:

```
{if logged_in_member_id == segment_2}
    {exp:external_entries:insert table="whatever" debug="n"}
        {insert:member_id}{segment_2}{/insert:member_id}
    {/exp:external_entries:insert}
{/if}
```

The problem is that the plugin code executes *regardless* of whether the conditional is met or not.

For example, even if `segment_2` **does not match** `logged_in_member_id`, the plugin still executes.

My understanding is that [simple conditionals](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html) are evaluated *before* plugins. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think (but not completely sure) that logged_in_member_id is parsed lately (see the point 9 in http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf). Maybe try to replace logged_in_member_id with a static value to ensure that theory ;)

If the test is positive, try http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee

Comment: This is correct - `{logged_in_member_id}` is a late-parsed variable, hence your issue. Moving your insert code to an embed should fix this parse order issue.

Comment: What if you wrap the whole thing in a {if logged_in} conditional?

Comment: You could try embedding your plugin from a template to parse later eg. {logged_in_member_id}{embed="mygroup/mytemplate_with_external_entries"}{/if}

Low Variables has an early parse option for logged in data too.